# Does 1-1 polymorphic association make sense?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have two models, Article and Document. Each needs an Editor i.e. contains the content body of the Article or Document.  A polymorphic association makes sense.

Article

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :editor, :as => :editable
end
```

Document

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :editor, :as => :editable
end
```

Editor

```
class Editor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :editable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

The Editor model contains the following attributes:

content, editable_id, editable_type (name of model i.e. Article or Document)

This all works fine but do I need it?

If I wish to access the content body for a given Article can I not just get the id of the editor field directly like so?

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
@editor_id = @article.editor.id
```

and perform my Editor find on that.

I don't see the benefit of the one-to-one polymorphic relationship in this case.  Can anyone set me straight?

Comment: editable_id is not unique ... I wish you could unask stupid questions on SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for your very specific question on why you can't do the following with out the polymorphic relationship:

> @article = Article.find(params[:id])
>
> @editor_id = @article.editor.id

The entire reason @article.editor.id works is because of the polymorphic relationship. It's going something on the lines of:

- You have a has_one :editor which means @article.editor = this editor model based on it's editable fields
- Now that you have found this editor model here's it's id

If you took out the has_one it would stop working. Also, you don't need to do a find at all because this is also true:

> @article = Article.find(params[:id])
>
> @editor = @article.editor

No for the larger question of is there a way to set this up with out using polymorphic at all.

To make things as simple as possible you could just put content fields in document and article. This would make sense if:

- You will always use the content field so you aren't taking up database space for nothing
- There is no special code, validation, etc that goes with the content field and would then be repeated in two places.

I'm going to assume by the fact that you have an Editor model there are functions, validations, etc in that model that require it to be its own entity to avoid code duplication.  At this point you have two routes you could go. The first would avoid polymorphic by putting the editor_id in Article and Document and making them belongs_to :editor. Yes, you avoid polymorphic behavior but you have some serious downsides:

- The Editor database table is referenced in multiple locations but there is nothing in the table to tell you who is using what column. Having had to "read" and "port" databases more often then I'd like to it's a good future consideration. (This isn't a problem in cases where you wouldn't use polymorphism because you would know all items in this table can only be linked to one other table.)
- Every time you want to use Editor in a model you have to add another migration to add editor_id to that model and modify Editor to have the link back to that model. (You could technically skip that step but for code readability you really want to mark what models it could be linked to. Especially if you are stuck doing the previous point.)

So that gets us back to your original setup. The polymorphic relationship does a few things:

- Makes it clear in the database who each row belongs to
- Lets you make another model have and editor with only code and not database changes
- Keeps all the functionality specific to Editor content in one nice spot

So, yes, I think the one to one polymorphic makes sense. It leads to:
 - an easier to maintain database
 - easier to add future functionality
 - clearer relationship

The only thing I would consider is if there is almost no code in Editor just dumping the field directly in the Article and Document models and dumping Editor completely.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear description. Yes, it all makes sense now. The main reason to push for a polymorphic relationship was to avoid code duplication and you are right, article.editor does only work because of the association. Thank you for taking the time to answer